# Object is possibly undefined

Tags: typescript

I have following type:

```js
type Person = {
  name: string 
  age: number
  value?: number
}
```

Also I have mock array of objects:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    age: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    age: 2
  }
]
```

Now I would like to add to each object in array property `value`

```js
 const newArr = arr.map(item => {
    return {
      ...item,
      value: fun(item)
    }
  })
```

And here is a function which add value

```js
const add = (item: Person): number => {
  return item.value + 1
}
```

Now we have a TypeScript problem:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
```

I am pretty sure that I can't do something like that because I need to return number?

```js
const add = (item: Person): number => {
  return item.value && item.value + 1
}
```

How should I handle this?

Comment: What kind of behaviour would you expect if value is actually undefined ?

Comment: If it would be undefined I dont want to create value property

Comment: How I can tell typescript that I am sure on 100% this will be never undefined

Comment: _"I dont want to create value property"_ - what does that mean? What should `add` return? The compiler is telling you about a legitimate problem - that property _might_ be undefined, according to the type information you've given it, in which case your function returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i prefer to use (??) [Nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) coalescing Operator

```
const add = (item: Person): number => {
  return (item?.value ?? 0) + 1
}
```

[you can see also](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)

Comment: How it works???

Comment: post updated...

Comment: there is no need for optional chain there item?. As the type of item is Person, TS will complain if you have a call site where the argument could be null/undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Since your value property is `number | undefined` TS complains about it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you defined `value` to be optional, your `add` function cannot be sure that it exists. Therefore, its behaviour is not well-defined. What should it return if an `item` is passed which has no `value` attribute?

You can either make `value` be a required attribute / create a new interface:

```
interface ValuedPerson extends Person {
    value: number;
}

const add = (item: ValuedPerson): number => {
    return item.value + 1
}
```

or add a default value, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72403981/11650238) suggests.

After OP's remark: You can tell TypeScript that it does exist by adding an exclamation mark:

```
const add = (item: Person): number => {
    return item!.value + 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is yelling at you because you are still not returning a *number*.

```js
const add = (item: Person): number => {
  return item.value && item.value + 1
}
```

This will return a *number* if `value` is present in `item`, if not, it will return *undefined*.

**EITHER**

Make `value` a required attribute.

**OR**

Do a ternary check.

```js
const add = (item: Person): number => {
    return item.value ? item.value + 1 : 0
}
```

I am assuming, you want to add 0 to `value` if `value` is not present.

Typescript should now be happy.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way to solve this

```
const add = (item: Person): number => {
  const newValue = item.value || ''
  return newValue  + 1`
}
```